# Is there anyway we can automatically get generated Typescript classes from VB.net server side classes?

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, vb.net, backend

I am working on a web app project , VB.net is the server (API) language and frontend is written in Angular (typescript) , each time when a class model is created in the vb.net the same needs to be manually repeated in front end typescript , is there anyway we can get this generated in typescript automatically for frontend  ?

I have given few try with typegen but it is only working with C#.

Comment: I'm a little surprised that a utility like `typegen` would be written based on source instead of by reflecting on the assembly.  The latter approach seems like it would be easier---no need to have your own C# parser, and it would automatically work with any .NET language.  Have you considered writing your own utility to do it?  I wouldn't imagine it would be too crazy to write.

Comment: *it is only working with C#.* - good job VB and C# are the same thing then?!

Comment: @CaiusJard If it's only working with C#, then it's presumably working at a source level and not an assembly level.  I haven't actually tried the product, though... maybe it really does work at an assembly level, and it would work with VB, but they just don't advertise that.

Comment: @Craig is right. I did this exact thing using reflection and it took less than an afternoon to get 100% of what I wanted. I'll post it on GitHub if you're interested. Either way please don't do it based on source. Yes when compiled to MSIL C# and VB are basically the same.

Comment: We use [TypeWriter](http://frhagn.github.io/Typewriter/) and it only works with C# too. That said, it is open-source so, if there's nothing else available, you could adapt it to work with VB yourself. Not sure how complicated that would be.

Comment: A thought also struck me; it might be possible to find something that does it by tripping via json.. Or maybe if you have the Json data that exemplifies the message you can use a pair of websites, something like QuickType.io for each end. Heck, if there isn't anything out there you could *make* something like QuickType.io :) - always annoyed me somewhat that it makes c# only

Answer (score 3):

I'm the creator of TypeGen, I noticed there is some discussion in the comments of the original post regarding TypeGen, but unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to comment, so I'll post an answer instead.

TypeGen works by reading assemblies and it uses Reflection to get the information about the types and perform the translation to TypeScript.

The reason it's described as a "C# to TypeScript" generator (and not ".NET to TypeScript") is because it was only tested with C# - there might be some differences in how VB.NET code is compiled to IL, and since I'm not an expert on VB.NET, I decided it would be safer to name it a "C# to TypeScript" generator.

You can try to generate TypeScript sources from .NET assemblies created with VB.NET with TypeGen and it might work, but it just hasn't been tested this way.

I hope this can provide some clarification.

Thanks,
Jacek

Comment: Can you provide a link to your TypeGen tooling/library? and/or quickstart instructions?

Comment: Sure, the GitHub page is https://github.com/jburzynski/TypeGen, there is also a quick start guide there.

More detailed documentation is at https://typegen.readthedocs.io/ (there is also a "Getting Started" section there, under "Overview | Getting started").

There is also a website: http://jburzynski.net/TypeGen , but it doesn't provide that much more information compared to the GitHub page and documentation (except for the "Donate" button), it's mostly for swag.